# React through Vscode, I want to push an update to github

Tags: reactjs, github

I have a Github repo made, and I have pushed an update before, but I did it with help. I still feel pretty lost, what would be the commands to commit the new update to GitHub through Vscode's terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If you have pushed to the repo before, the following commands should do it:

```
git add .

git commit -m "your commit message"

git push
```